# Magento 2 customer logged out if clicked checkout button more than one

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer

If I clicked "checkout" button , while page is loading to checkout page , I click the button again, the system will make me logged out.

Have someone met this problem?

Comment: check consol or log file for error description if any.

Comment: no error or console log are there

Comment: are you using VertexSMB?

Comment: @Ricky.C have you found any solution?